# Java errors when compiling

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I'm trying to compile the following java app: http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/resource/InstallCert.java (as outlined [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find), but I get a few errors:

```
    C:\foo>javac InstallCert.java
    InstallCert.java:122: ';' expected
        for (int b : bytes) {
                   ^
InstallCert.java:129: illegal start of expression
    }
    ^
2 errors
```

I am using version jdk 1.4.2_11

Comment: What's your version of Java? (javac -version)

Comment: By deleting the other errors, you made Michael Borgwrdt's answer seem inapplicable. You should have left it in there and just added an update.

Comment: My apologies.  He'll get the answer credit anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that your java compiler does not recognize the class `StringBuilder`. Since it is in the `java.lang` package which does not need to be imported, the only explanation is that your JDK is Java 1.4 or older, since `StringBuilder` was only introduced in Java 1.5

So you need to update your Java installation (or if you have multiple JDKs installed, make sure you use the right one).

**Update:**
The new error is *also* caused by the old Java version, because the for-each loop syntax was only added in Java 1.5 as well. Update your JDK already. 1.4 is really, really old and should not be used anymore.

Comment: +1 for full answer on original unedited question. The question was modified since and does not show the `StringBuilder` compile error.

Comment: Much obliged.  I am completely green with java.

Comment: Lucas, I changed the question because I had actually made a tweak to the code, but then reverted it to the original source so the errors were in hierarchical order.

Comment: @Lucas, @Angry: Funny thing is, the cause of the problem as well as the solution are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer Java compiler. That for statement will only compile in Java 5 or above.